# Catel WindowNotRegisteredException

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, catel

I am trying to use the `IUIVisualizerService` (Catel.MVVM v 4.0.0) to show a dialog based on a VM.

My code is something like the following:

```
private async void ShowConfiguration()
{
    // Get the configuration object
    ApplicationConfiguration conf = //get configuration

    // Create the view model with it
    ConfigurationViewModel vm = new ConfigurationViewModel(conf);

    var serviceLocator = Catel.IoC.ServiceLocator.Default;

    var uiService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<IUIVisualizerService>();

    var res = await uiService.ShowDialog(vm);

    if (res.HasValue && res.Value)
    {
        // save the configuration
    }
}
```

My VM Full name is:

> MyProject.ViewModels.Configuration.ConfigurationViewModel

The corresponding view (should be):

> MyProject.Views.Configuration.ConfigurationView

I assume this default naming convention:

> [AS].Views.[VM]View

Should do the mapping where [AS] = MyProject and [VM] = Configuration.Configuration... but I am getting `WindowNotRegisteredException`:

> There is no window registered as 'MyProject.ViewModels.Configuration.ConfigurationViewModel'

What am I missing? I am quite sure the opposite this is working (finding VM according to view).

BTW, I can overcome this by registering the association explicitly:

```
var serviceLocator = Catel.IoC.ServiceLocator.Default;
var uiService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<Catel.Services.IUIVisualizerService>();
uiService.Register<ConfigurationViewModel, ConfigurationView>();
```

But I prefer to have things working "off-the-box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespaces you use are not supported by default. You should use either these namespaces:

MyProject.Configuration.ViewModels.ConfigurationViewModel
MyProject.Configuration.Views.ConfigurationView

OR add a new [naming convention](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Naming+conventions) to the IViewLocator:

viewLocator.NamingConventions.Add("MyProject.Views.Configuration.[VM]View");

OR register the view manually:

viewLocator.Register(typeof(ConfigurationViewModel), typeof(ConfigurationView));

Comment: The VM name is derived just from the name of the VM class and do not include namespaces?